# Creating index on nested json which is string in postgres jsonb

Tags: java, postgresql

I want to query jsonb column with the nested field.

```
select * 
from TABLE_NAME 
where is_active=true 
and extra_info->'leaderboardConfig'->>'tier'= ??? 
order by id desc limit ?"
```

here extra_info has a lot of other information. while I am interested in leaderboardConfig.tier = "Bronze";

My extra info looks like this

```
{
    "info":"something",
     "inf2":"something",
    "leaderboardConfig": {
        "profile":123,
        "info1":"something",
        "info2":"something",
        "tier":"Bronze"

    }
}
```

how do i create index on extra_info->'leaderboardConfig'->>'tier'

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how do i create index on extra_info->'leaderboardConfig'->>'tier'

Answer (score 2):

Just use the exact expression you use in your query when creating the index:

```
create index on the_table ( (extra_info->'leaderboardConfig'->>'tier') );
```

Note the extra pair of parentheses which is required because the index is only built on a single expression.